# angular chosen multi select dynamic appending of option is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am wanted  to add new values on the fly to a chosen.js multiselect.
(refereed http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

Multi select is working fine, but i wanted provision for the user to add the item of the drop down on fly

I a using angularjs and mongodb when i add a item using bootstarp model the model in the controller gets populated but it is not reflected in the dropdown

I am a new bee i understood i want to make some changes in the plugin but don't have any idea how to do it please help[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a directive called [Angular Chosen](https://github.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen) to use on Angular with Chosen.
You just need to add `chosen` to your select.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['localytics.directives']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'Multiple Angular Chosen Example using ngModel and ngOptions';
  $scope.state = [3, 2];
  
  //Static items
  $scope.states = [
    {id: 1, tite: 'Alaska'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Arizona'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Arkansas'},
    {id: 4, title: 'California'}
  ];
  
  //Remote items
  $http({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'
  }).success(function(posts) {
    console.log(posts);
    $scope.states = posts;
  });
});
```

```css
select {width: 400px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/leocaseiro/angular-chosen/master/dist/angular-chosen.min.js">
</script>
<link data-require="chosen@*" data-semver="1.0.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.0/chosen.min.css" />
  

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">    
<select chosen multiple ng-model="state" ng-options="s.id as s.title for s in states">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
</div>
```